# Safely parsing a string to a boolean

Tags: scala

```
import scala.util.Try

val m = Map("a" -> "false", "b" -> "true")

Try(m.get("a").map(_.toBoolean)).getOrElse(false)
```

What I want to return is a Boolean, not a Try or an Option but currently the Try is getting in the way.

Comment: You cannot "safely" parse an arbitrary string to anything. Describe your problem better, please. What's wrong with the `Try`?

Comment: This can be simplified to `Try(m("a").toBoolean).getOrElse(false)`. You'll safely get `true` or `false` without the `Option`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you simply define `m` to have type: `Map[String, Boolean]`, i.e. `Map("a" -> false, "b" -> true)`?

Comment: Simpler: `m.withDefaultValue("false")("b") == "true"` or `m.get("b").map(_ == "true").getOrElse(false)` ... but just know that just like with try, you're ignoring errors like key not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're interested in returning `true` if the string successfully parses to a true boolean, and false otherwise (e.g. "True" = `true` and "true" = `true`, but "false" and "abc" are both `false`).

Here's how to do that with your model:

```
val m = Map("a" -> "false", "b" -> "true")

val aBool = Try(m.get("a").map(_.toBoolean).getOrElse(false)).getOrElse(false)
```

As good practice, I would suggest avoiding control flow using exceptions.  The `Try` monad is nice to write, but performs much worse than slightly-uglier alternatives.  Take a look at [this performance chart](http://ithare.com/infographics-operation-costs-in-cpu-clock-cycles/) -- if you're ever encountering values that don't parse successfully, you are shooting your performance in the foot.

Using some string comparisons will make this workflow orders of magnitude faster.

```
val m = Map("a" -> "false", "b" -> "true")

val aBool = m.get("a").exists(_.toLowerCase() == "true")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you attempt to do may fail in (at least) two different ways :

- the map `m` does not have a key `"a"` (because the type `Map` does not encode the fact that it is defined at `"a"`)
- if `m` is defined at `"a"` you cannot be sure that its value is a string which can be meaningfully translated to a boolean (because the type `String` does not encode this translation in a pure way)

Therefore, it is a very good idea to wrap the call to `_.toBoolean` in a `Try` block, and to use the `get` method on the map, as you did. However, you need to specify what to do on the failed cases.

In the question, you used `getOrElse` on the `Try` block, to recover from the error for the translation from `String` to `Boolean`. However, you have not dealt with the other failure possibility, so what you have in your `Try` block is an `Option[Boolean]`, and you cannot use `false` as default value.

If you do no recovery at all, you get

`Try(m.get("a").map(_.toBoolean)): Try[Option[Boolean]]`

You can then use `.getOrElse(<default-value>)` twice (once for the `Try`, once for the `Option`) to get a value of type `Boolean`.

You can also consider that all errors will be caught by the `Try` block and not bother ensuring that `m` is defined at `"a"` (however, I would not encourage to do so, since it is not a very functional way to do things):

`Try(m("a").toBoolean).getOrElse(false)`

You can also consider that only the `toBoolean` call must be wrapped in a `Try` since everything else is pretty pure. Moreover, you know that this method has only one way to fail, so you can convert the `Try` to an `Option`:

`m.get("a").map(s => Try(s.toBoolean).toOption): Option[Option[Boolean]]`

Or, if you do not want to distinguish between the two errors:

`m.get("a").flatMap(s => Try(s.toBoolean).toOption): Option[Boolean]`

In each case, one or two `getOrElse` will extract the desired value, while ensuring no error will be thrown.